# Where can I find source code for JFXPanel in JavaFX 2.2?

Tags: java, javafx-2

In my app I'm seeing some strange stacktraces comming from `JFXPanel.java` which I'd like to investigate further. Unfortunately, with JDK 7 only the runtimes of JavaFX 2.2 are present.

I know that JFX code is only partially open source, and here is the main branch of that project: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt

However downloading and unpacking the ZIP source code does not yield a `JFXPanel` class file. I can see it easily with downloading official JDK 8 early access, though.

Where can I find this source code? (I'm using JDK 7 u 40)

Comment: As I understand it, JavaFX is going to become "more" open source over time. I guess JFXPanel is yet not part of that "more". :)

Comment: Darn, I was afraid that this could be the case. This is quite silly, as this class is the main bridge between the Swing and JFX apps...

Comment: Magnilex is right and there are fairly no bugfixes for FX 2.2 coming along because all force is going into FX8 (released with Java8 in March) - did you test on the latest OpenJFK8 builds

Comment: I don't think my team will be aiming at JDK 8 anytime soon. Do you think this JFX8 can work with JDK 7?

Comment: Answering my latest comment - no it wont. It's already pre-built with JDK8: `javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Comment: No - there's a back port for the Android/iOS guys so you could give this one a spin (naturally this is not supported by Oracle directly) - it would be interesting although to find out if your very problem got fixed there so that Oracle has the possibility to fix it maybe until you switch to JDK8 in future?

Comment: I was lucky enough to run my project in JDK8 without source code modifications. It indeed turned out that my problem is gone in JFX8. I'll file a bug in the JFX2.2 jira.